# How to scroll down in lighting component Quick Action Pop-Up

Tags: lightning-aura-components, visual-workflow, popup, lightning-quickaction

I used a lighting component to display a Flow in Global Quick Action.

Here is my code, everything is working as expected :

```
    <!-- ,force:lightningQuickActionWithoutHeader -->
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,force:lightningQuickAction" access="global" >

<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.init}" />
<lightning:flow aura:id="flowData" onstatuschange="{!c.handleStatusChange}" />
</aura:component>

({
init : function (component) {
// Find the component whose aura:id is “flowData”
var flow = component.find("flowData");
// In that component, start your flow. Reference the flow’s Unique Name.
flow.startFlow("Create_Feedback");
},



handleStatusChange : function (component, event) {    
    //alert('event.getParam '+event.getParam('status'));
    if(event.getParam('status') === "FINISHED") {
        $A.get("e.force:closeQuickAction").fire();
    }        
}
}
)
```

But when I start using the global action, a pop-up is opening in the right of my screen and I can't scroll down to use my flow.

Is this a way to have the ability to scroll down in this pop-up ?
Or to directly open the pop up in full screen ?

the pop up i can't used :

[image]
Thank you for your answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ui:scrollerwrapper](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/ui:scrollerWrapper/documentation) like this,

```
<ui:scrollerWrapper class="scrollerSize">
        <lightning:flow aura:id="flowData" onstatuschange="{!c.handleStatusChange}" />
    </ui:scrollerWrapper>
```

You can also utilize [slds-scrollable](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/utilities/scrollable/) using `<div>` tags.